# NoMethodError: undefined method `image_will_change!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, carrierwave

I am receiving this error when I try an upload an image to a post. The image is pointing to an error in `posts_controller.rb`, specifically the line

```
 @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
```

I have run the following commands with no success

```
heroku restart
rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Here is the error log...

```
Started POST "/topics/16/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-13 15:54:00 -0400
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NSz0oNqCRm9R3w820fLmaqUhnUYpfo+xB2/cp2FxrFE=", "post"=>{"title"=>"jlajsdlajs", "body"=>"jaljdslajdlasjdlkajsldkajslkj", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb568702a18 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/3k/1093ljv50p9617s4vn704r9w0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140913-844-1cs5s69>, @original_filename="art-painting-gerome-bethseba_wallcoo.com.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"art-painting-gerome-bethseba_wallcoo.com.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Post", "topic_id"=>"16"}
  Topic Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "16"]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `image_will_change!' for #<Post:0x007fb56b839078>:
  activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:167:in `method_missing'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:38:in `image='
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:29:in `block in assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/core.rb:468:in `init_attributes'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/core.rb:185:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:189:in `build_association'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:255:in `build_record'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:114:in `build'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:229:in `build'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:23:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__3615575638932885909__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3700456067185870614__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: This looks like output from a local log file, so I *think* you're trying to make this work on your local environment. `heroku` commands affect the production environment only and won't help with a development environment problem. 

My best *guess* is that the migration that adds the `image` column to the posts table isn't being run or hasn't been created yet. Check your migrations directory contains a migration that adds an image column to the posts table. HTH.